# How to calculate input text length using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. I have designed a simple program where I have taken two text boxes which take input and display the input count next to them. There is a third text box which shows the total sum of the inputs. The program is working fine. But I want this to be done using components, not by this way. All the three text boxes should be components and do the same task. 
Kindly help.

This is my code.

HTML :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    Enter value : <input v-model="groupId" /> {{groupId.length}}
    <br /><br />
    Enter value : <input v-model="groupId1" /> {{groupId1.length}}
    <br /><br />
    Output : <input v-model="groupId2" value="{{groupId.length + groupId1.length}}" readonly />
</body>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.27/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="textLength.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript Code :-

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        groupId: null,
        groupId1: null
        ,
        groupId2: null
    }

});

Comment: Try something first. SO is not a free coding service. Here's docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Are you trying to do that with each framework available? Your questions history is so strange.